# Get Selection Marks label with Azure Document Intelligence Api ( Form recognizer)

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

I am using Azure Form Recognizer Api in my tester Project. I am testing selection marks on this image
[image]

I am getting correct results, but its only showing selected or unselected, i also want label that which field is selected, for example in the image above : Bars Selected

[image]